# How to copy illustrator opacity mask via script?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, mask, illustrator-scripting, script

Situation - I have a group that contains some objects partially covered by opacity mask to emulate blurred edge. It is very easy to copy-paste such group in Illustrator - and copied group contais the same masks.

But in case if I'm trying to copy this group via script

```
var copyGroup = group.duplicate();
```

in copied group all masks are 100% white - so they just hide everything, that under them. Did somebody encounters such problem and maybe found the way to solve it?

Comment: Can you give more info on what the whole script does & more of your code?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is not the right answer but i think it could be usefull anyway:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2368829

Comment: It would be even more useful if you transcripted the main part to your answer; we don't like depending on external links for content.